# Any way to unzip file on react-native

Tags: react-native, filesystems, unzip

Managed to download .zip file to my filesystem on mobile phone. But after a while realised I can't find a way how to unzip that file. As I tried with:

- https://github.com/plrthink/react-native-zip-archive
- https://github.com/remobile/react-native-zip

First one dies immidiately after requiring, getting error "Cannot read property 'unzip' of undefined" (followed instructions carefully)

And the second one dies because it's dependant on codrova port to react native which also doesn't work.

Any suggestions or way to solve these problems?

Using react-native 0.35, testing on Note4 with android 5.1.1.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: There's no code. If I only import it in my project build fails (no other code what so ever). Which means I've made mistake while adding it to project (but been following instructions 3 times now, so that isn't much likely) or module isn't working properly.

Comment: You might taking wrong steps to add project.

Comment: I'll try it again. But i'm pretty skeptic about this. As I noted before I've followed instructions 3 times already.

Comment: ok let me try to integrate

Comment: That would be awsome, let me know if you manage to do it properly. Also please add info on which react you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133065/discussion-between-codesingh-and-bepo-krivic).

Comment: are you using this lib for android?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this problem? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @spacek33z Indeed I did manage to fix it. I've added solution

Comment: how did you download the `.zip` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage in the end solve my problem:

using react-native-zip-archive

the solution was to change code inside:
RNZipArchiveModule.java file which is inside module

The changes that needed to be applied are written in this comment:
https://github.com/plrthink/react-native-zip-archive/issues/14#issuecomment-261712319

So credits to hujiudeyang for solving problem.

Answer (score 1):

go to this direction :
node_modules\react-native-zip-archive\android\src\main\java\com\rnziparchive\RNZipArchiveModule.java

and replace this codes instead of unzip method

```
public static void customUnzip(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)));
    try {
      ZipEntry ze;
      int count;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        File file = new File(targetDirectory, ze.getName());
        File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
        if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
          throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " +
                  dir.getAbsolutePath());
        if (ze.isDirectory())
          continue;
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
          while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
            fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
        } finally {
          fout.close();
        }
            /* if time should be restored as well
            long time = ze.getTime();
            if (time > 0)
                file.setLastModified(time);
            */
      }
    } finally {
      zis.close();
    }
  }

  //**************************

  @ReactMethod
  public void unzip(final String zipFilePath, final String destDirectory, final String charset, final Promise promise) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          customUnzip(new File(zipFilePath ) , new File(destDirectory));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }




         }
    }).start();
  }
```