# Javascript improve downloading speed

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, react-native-ios

I am using React Native and the problem I have come across is downloading thumbnails.
Actually, I am downloading 29889 thumbs and it's too slow.
Here's my code:

```
recursive_thumb(skip, count) {
  if (skip < this.state.totalMarkerCount) {
    let thumbs = []
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
      thumbs.push(this.downloadThumb(this.state.thumbs[skip + i]))
    }
    Promise.all(thumbs)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
          fetchedCount: skip + count
        })
        this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
    })
     .catch(reason => {
       this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
       this.setState({
         totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
         fetchedCount: skip + count
       })
     })
} else {
  setThumbDownloaded()
  this.checkTownDownloaded()
}


downloadThumb(element) {
  console.log(element)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    RNFetchBlob.config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache: true,
    path: `${DocumentDirectoryPath}/thumbs/${element}`
  })
    .fetch(
      'GET',
      `https://www.searchforsites.co.uk/app/images/default/${element}`,
      {
        // some headers ..
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      resolve(true)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.log('Error: ', err);
      // this.setState({ modalOpen: false, regionUpdated: true });
      // this.findUser();
      reject(true)
    })
})
}
```

If we can use thread it would be a good experience.
Downloading whole data takes 15 min.

Is there any genius solution?

Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: How about lazy loading the images? Depending on your application's front end needs, you could set images to load in batches or entirely in background.

Answer (score 0):

If your application's front end doesn't need all the images at once, then try reworking your app to lazy load the images for better performance.

1. [See the React Lazy Load npm package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-image)
2. [This blog post walks through an example.](https://medium.com/jsguru/react-image-lazy-loading-component-246e0cdcce02)

Lazy loading will definitely help improve performance/load times.

Also worth considering, you may want to rework your application and template structure to limit how many images appear per page.  Maybe the page can have an infinite scroll behavior, with additional images loaded in batches via Ajax, and not all up front.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have to download all images at once.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Consider WHY and IF you need 30.000 images at once. This sounds like a bad design choice.

Solution 2: Put them on a zip file, and then unzip that file: [Any way to unzip file on react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630882/any-way-to-unzip-file-on-react-native)

Problem with solution 2 is that I am not so sure it would work since you are adding a lot of images that the RN resolver does not know about.